# Any tips or suggestions to this idea/architecture?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

We have a multi services application. We have moved a method that involves a DB access to a separate component that is exposed by a WCF endpoint.

We have 2 options:
1.  A WCF call to the method.
2.  Call directly to the method, resolved by our DI engine.
The system performance is a critical issue, so we want to switch between option 1 and option 2 via configuration file with out recompiling client application.
Any tips or suggestions to this idea/architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can teach Unity to resolve WCF services by interface. So it does not matter wether you resolve a local implementation of your service or a WCF one. You will always inject an *IMyService* into your classes. It's just a change of your configuration.

You can configure the extension to use app.config or WCF discovery or explicitely specify *Binding* and *EndpointAddress* in code.

See the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com) for further information. The source code is located in *TecX.ServiceModel.AutoMagic*. Some tests that demonstrate the usage can be found in *TecX.ServiceModel.Test*

---

**Update**

Define an interface for your service (e.g. *IMyService*) and decorate it with the necessary attributes (*DataContract*, *OperationContract*). Implement that interface (e.g. in class *MyService*). *MyService* calls your method. Now tell Unity to either map *IMyService* directly to *MyService* or add the container extension that allows you to map *IMyService* to a proxy generated by the WCF *ChannelFactory*. Deploy your service and you are done. Unity will inject whatever implementation of *IMyService* into the constructors of those classes that need them.

Comment: "we want to switch between option 1 and option 2 via configuration file with out recompiling client application"   I know know the tradeoffs, main point is how can i implement this archirtecture.?

Comment: @shahzad If my answer was helpful it would be great if you could mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid an extra WCF layer if system performance is a critical issue and there aren't any other requirements driving the design this way. You might perform some  performance tests to see if its overhead would be acceptable to you though. In the end you can decide which option is better for you and so, remove the need to switch.

Comment: If there is a need for some of the WCF features (e.g. encrypted calls, authentication, identity propagation, transactions voting, authorization, security audits, transaction propagation, calls timeout, reliability, durability, error masking, fault isolation, buffering and throttling, data versioning tolerance, remotability, interoperability, queuing, discovery, ...) WCF is the best choice you can make. No other framework on the market can compete with its performance.